# System.BadImageFormatException thrown in unit test using Autofixture GuardClauseAssertion

Tags: unit-testing, idioms, autofixture, badimageformatexception

I have a unit test written with xUnit, AutoFixture, using [AutoFixture Idioms GuardClauseAssertion](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/Idioms/GuardClauseAssertion.cs) to check for guard clauses in my assemblies' classes:

```cs
[InlineData(typeof (ProjectOneClass))]
[InlineData(typeof (ProjectTwoClass))]
[InlineData(typeof (ProjectThreeClass))]
[InlineData(typeof (ProjectFourClass))]
[InlineData(typeof (ProjectFiveClass))]
[Theory(DisplayName = "Classes guard against null arguments in assemblies")]
public void GuardAgainstNullArgumentsInAssemblies(Type assemblyHintType)
{
    // arrange
    IFixture fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    fixture.Behaviors.Add(new TracingBehavior());
    var assertion = new GuardClauseAssertion(fixture);

    // assert
    assertion.Verify(assemblyHintType.Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t =>
            !t.Name.Equals("MyWebServices") &&
            !t.Name.Equals("MyComputer") &&
            !t.Name.Equals("MyProject") &&
            !t.Name.Equals("MyApplication") &&
            !t.IsInterface &&
            !t.IsGenericType &&
            !t.IsCompilerGenerated() &&
            !t.IsStaticClass()
        ));
}
```

I make my assertion with filters to focus the unit test on only the appropriate classes I wrote, and use *hint types* to target specific assemblies. I pass these *hint types* in using `InlineData(typeof(...))`, so that the test is once for each *hint type*.

The tests pass for 3 out of the 5 tests, after having a few test runs which pointed out code where I forgot to put in null guards, but the other two tests yield the following exception:

> System.BadImageFormatException An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)    at
>
> System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>   at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()    at
>   System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Idioms.GuardClauseAssertion.AutoGenericArgument.get_Value()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Idioms.GuardClauseAssertion.AutoGenericMethod.get_Value()
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Idioms.GuardClauseAssertion.Verify(MethodInfo methodInfo)
>   at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Idioms.IdiomaticAssertion.Verify(MethodInfo[] methodInfos)
>   at Ploeh.AutoFixture.Idioms.IdiomaticAssertion.Verify(Type type)    at
>   Ploeh.AutoFixture.Idioms.IdiomaticAssertion.Verify(Type[] types)    at
>   NullGuardTests.GuardAgainstNullArgumentsInNonModelAssemblies(Type assemblyHintType)
>   in NullGuardTests.cs: line 58

I add `TracingBehavior` to the the `IFixture` instance for more visibility, and it shows:

> ```cs
> Requested: Infrastructure.Logging.IErrorAggregator errorAggregator
>   Requested: Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.SeededRequest
> ```
>
> ... and on and on and on...

I've looked at the very first item and the very last item in this long trace to try and figure out how they are different from the very first/last items shown in the successful tests' traces, but I haven't been able to find any meaningful differences.

I'm assuming that the last item in the trace is the last activity from the `IFixture` before the exception.

**How do I get more visibility into an exception like this, beyond what I've done so far?**

- Every targeted assembly is targeting .NET 4.0
- Every targeted assembly has the same settings in the Build configuration (AnyCPU)
- Every targeted assembly is written in VB.NET (although the unit test is in C#)

Ideas? Thank you in advance.

**Update 29 MAR 2014**

I still haven't been able to figure out what's happening here, but I'm hoping that leaving the question up will at least be a sanity check for someone else with the same problem, who discovers this question here. Workload permitting, I'll work on submitting a repro.

Comment: I don't have any concrete ideas about how to proceed with this error, as this is not a known bug in AutoFixture. Is there a simple way to reproduce this behaviour? In my experience, `BadImageFormatException` is usually caused by some fundamental problem with compatibility or similar, and rarely a particular piece of code... What I'm trying to say is that it may be a framework issue rather than an issue with AutoFixture. However, it's not often I encounter that particular exception. Not that I want to dismiss AutoFixture's responsibility in this matter, but a repro would be nice at this point.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Agreed - a repro would be nice. I'm going to take a closer look at the five different VB.NET projects being targeted and try to figure out what's different about the three that don't throw the exception. Maybe some assembly reference differences. I'll also see if I can create a simple repro.